# What ならねー means?

Tags: meaning, words

I am playing a game. I sit in an empty train and character says:

> ホント、よく廃線にならねーよな

I don't know what naranēyona should mean.

I am just speculating, that it might mean "Really, It can be abandoned that's okay".

Google translate says it is:
"Really, It is often abolished line" Which checks out with what I was thinking, but still don't know, what ならねー  means.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Checking Google Translate wastes your time and leaves you worse off than if you’d never checked it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ならねー is a very informal, kind of slang-y shift in pronunciation of ならない.

You'll often see diphthong (two-vowel) portions of words flattened into monophthong (single-vowel) variants in informal speech.  Additional examples you might encounter:

- すごい → すげー
- たかい → たけー
- わからない → わからねー → わかんねー

The ねー ending seems to be the most common spelling, but depending on the writer, you might also see (in rough order of frequency) ねえ, ねぇ, or ねい.

Comment: Thank you very much. This now makes sense :)